# When is it a good idea to turn off atime and diratime?

Tags: linux, performance, optimization

I've read that turning off `atime` and `diratime` can be beneficial to I/O performance, but I've never seen a good example of what would and would not benefit. When should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a solid example of when you would specify noatime in the options for a partition, imagine a data partition containing the files for a database.  This database is mainly read from (not written to) and the queries are frequent and small in size.  If you have atime enabled, every read operation (fast) that hit the disk would actually turn into a write operation (slow) because atime would have to be updated every time something is accessed.

This is particularly noticeable when you are using a potentially slow disk (think EBS on Amazon with some performance issues).

So, in any case where you expect to be doing a lot of reading from a filesystem and you wan to prevent latency due to disk IO, turn off atime :)

Answer (score 1):

`atime` is the time of last access. That means that it has to be updated on disk each time a file is read, even if there is no other modification in the data/metadata of the file.

And since most programs read files, even whether they do not write at them, it is **always beneficial** for the performance to turn off this options.

Unless, of course, you need it. Because, as you probably know, `atime` is mandated by Posix, and there are some old software out there that relies on it.

Comment: I would suggest to keep atime turned on for filesystems which are not changed much (/var, /usr, ...). It is better for troubleshooting to actually see when each file was last accessed. BTW some filesystems support delayed/cached atime, so that it does not hurt IO so much.